# jquery not work in magento

Tags: php, jquery, magento

jQuery does not work in Magento. I want to show a time countdown. It does not work. Here is my [**site link**](http://lannettechnology.info/shooln). Here is a second id and have a time difference value. It prints the value but JavaScript is not showing time count like as daily deal.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function updateClock(id)
     {
        var pid = id;
        var currentSeconds1 = jQuery("#hello" + pid ).val();
        mySeconds = currentSeconds1 - 1;
        jQuery("#second" + pid ).val(mySeconds);
        alert(currentSeconds1);
        if(mySeconds == 0){
           location.reload(); 
        }
        else{ 
        var currentdays = Math.floor(mySeconds/86400);
        var remainiday = mySeconds%86400;
        var currentHours = Math.floor(remainiday/3600);
        var myHours = remainiday%3600;
        var currentMinutes = Math.floor(myHours/60);
        var currentSeconds = myHours%60;
        // Compose the string for display
        currentHours = (currentHours < 10? '0' : '') + currentHours; 
        currentMinutes = (currentMinutes < 10? '0' : '') + currentMinutes;
        currentSeconds = (currentSeconds < 10? '0' : '') + currentSeconds;
        var currentTimeString = currentdays + ' Days ' + currentHours + "h : " +                     currentMinutes + "m : " + currentSeconds +"s";
        var t = jQuery("#clock" + pid ).html(currentTimeString);
        }
     }
</script>
```

And the magento code

```
    <?php foreach ($productCollection-&gt;getItems() as $_product): ?>
    <div class="time-left" style="font-weight: bold; color:#ff0000; font-size: 13px;">Time Left : 
    <span id="cl"></span>
    <?php 
        $date1 =date("Y-m-d H:i:s", Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time())); 
        $date2 = date("Y-m-d 23:59:59", strtotime($_product->getSpecialToDate()));
        $timeFirst  = strtotime($date1);
        $timeSecond = strtotime($date2);
        echo $differenceInSeconds = $timeSecond - $timeFirst;
    ?>
    <input type="button" id="sec" value="<?php echo $differenceInSeconds ?>" /></div>
    <div class="product-image">
    <a href="%3C?php%20echo%20$_product-%3EgetProductUrl()%20?%3E"
    title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, &#39;small_image&#39;), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
        <img src="%3C?php%20echo%20$this-%3Ehelper(&#39;catalog/image&#39;)-%3Einit($_product,%20&#39;small_image&#39;)-%3Eresize(161,123);%20?%3E"
        width="161" height="123" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, &#39;small_image&#39;), null, true) ?>" />
    </a>
    </div>
    <span id="clock&lt;?php echo $_product-&gt;getId() ?&gt;"></span> 
    <?php  
        $date1 =date("Y-m-d H:i:s", Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time())); 
        $date2 = date("Y-m-d 23:59", strtotime($_product->getSpecialToDate()));
        $timeFirst  = strtotime($date1);
        $timeSecond = strtotime($date2);
        $differenceInSeconds = $timeSecond - $timeFirst;
    ?>
    <form>
        <input type="hidden" id="hello" value="12" /> 
        <input type="hidden" id="second&lt;?php echo $_product-&gt;getId() ?&gt;" value="<?php echo $differenceInSeconds ?>" />
    </form>
    <div class="product-info">
        <h3 class="product-name">
            <a href="%3C?php%20echo%20$_product-%3EgetProductUrl()%20?%3E" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>">
                <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>
            </a>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <?php //if($isShowDescription == 1):?>
<?php endforeach?>
```

Comment: use jQuery.noConflict() before  updateClock function

Comment: You mustn't have 2 versions of jquery loading - remove the one introduced by the product slider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you are using `Prototype.js` as well and are not using `jquery noconflict`.

I reviewed the page source and `/*var jns = jQuery.noConflict();*/` is commented. Please check this may be the case.

And change it as `var jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();` so you can use it or as per your requirements.
It is best option to create a separate Javascript file for noConflict and include it just after the main jquery library.

Comment: it seems you are using more than one version of jquery on the page. But i saw you are showing timer as alert and it is changing the time as well.